Execute "env" with execve() in C
Why when I run this code with any other commands (like "date" "pwd" or "ls") in gives output on screen, but with env not? Path is correct, what exactly is the issue? It is a part of Minishell project which consists in replicating part of the functionality of bash shell.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
char *argv[] = {"env", NULL};

    if (execve("/usr/bin/env", argv, NULL) == -1) {
        perror("execve");
        return 1;
    }

    // This line will only be reached if execve fails
    printf("This won't be printed if execve succeeds.\n");

    return 0;

}


You're passing an empty environment in envp, so what do you expect to be printed?  If you want env to print some output, you need to give it some environment variables to print.

Try using execv instead of execve. Then it will inherit your environment instead of you having to pass it explicitly.

I thought if NULL it inherits env var from system directly, it is not?

What do you mean, "from system"?  Do you mean that you expected it to inherit from the caller?  If so, where did you read that?  POSIX doesn't allow a null pointer as envp argument, although some implementations such as Linux support it as meaning an empty array.

Passing a null pointer as the "environment" argument to execve is non-standard; on Linux, it's the same as passing an empty environment.  Therefore, there is nothing for env to print.
To get some output, we need to pass some values in the environment:
    const char *argv[] = {"env", NULL};
    const char *envp[] = {"foo=bar", NULL};

    if (execve("/usr/bin/env", argv, envp) == -1) {
        perror("execve");
        return 1;
    }

See this note in the Linux manual:

On  Linux,  argv and envp can be specified as NULL.  In both
cases, this    has the same effect as specifying the argument as a
pointer  to  a  list    containing  a  single  null pointer.  Do not
take advantage of this non‐standard and nonportable misfeature!  On
many other UNIX systems, specifying argv as NULL will result in an
error (EFAULT).   Some  other  UNIX    systems treat the
envp==NULL case the same as Linux.


Or use execv (instead of execve) to retain the current environment.

If you do not provide any environment arguments to execve, it will not be able to display any variables since none are given. Ensure that the /usr/bin/env binary exists; it is possible that it could be a built-in command.
